# Displaying component property from record provider is undefined

Tags: ionic-framework

I am creating an ionic app. In this modal, I want a select with options populated from my Provider (called recordProvider). categories should hold an array of objects from the recordProvider.
The name property of these objects is what goes in the select.

I am able to log categories immediately after it is assigned from recordsProvider and it shows all the proper records perfectly. However, the next line logs the length at 0. Most importantly, the UI errors with "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

1. Why does categories have this inconsistent value?
2. If it is just an issue of timing and categories will have the correct data in a moment, why isn't it updated in the UI? Isn't that the whole get with Angular?
3. How do I fix it?

Modal ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams,ViewController } from 'ionic- angular';
    import { RecordsProvider } from './../../providers/records/records';

    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-add-modal',
      templateUrl: 'add-modal.html',
    })
    export class AddModalPage {
      categories:object[] = [];

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public viewCtrl : ViewController, public recordProvider: RecordsProvider) {
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.categories = this.recordProvider.getAllExpenseCategories();
        console.log(this.categories);
        console.log(this.categories.length);
      }

      public closeModal(){
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
      }
    }
```

Modal HTML

```
    <ion-content padding>
    <h1 (click)="getCat()">Hello</h1>
    <p>{{categories[0].name}}</p>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>categories</ion-label>
      <ion-select>
          <ion-option ng-repeat="obj of categories" value="{{obj.name}}">{{obj.name}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-content>
```

EDIT RecordsProvider

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class RecordsProvider {

  getAllExpenseCategories(){
    let categories = [];
    this.storage.forEach( (value, key, index)=>{
      if(key.indexOf("Exp") == 0){
        categories.push(value);
      }
    });
    return categories;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your record provider? guessing that your method there is async? Please share this method: getAllExpenseCategories()

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Thanks so much for responding! I edited to add the method

Answer (score 0):

Ionic Storage (localForage) uses async API, so I would make sure you write your methods with it accordingly, I would re-write the getAllExpenseCategories to leverage promise which is returned by storage:

```
  getAllExpenseCategories(){
    let categories = [];
    this.storage.forEach( (value, key, index)=>{
      if(key.indexOf("Exp") == 0){
        categories.push(value);
      }
    }).then(()=>{
        return categories;
    })
  }
```

In your case it seems like your method was returning empty array to the component, before storage completed its forEach cycle.

Let me know if this helped